# undefined method `attr_accessible' with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, rails-admin, attr-accessible

I am using Rails 4.1.1, ruby 2.1, mongodb, mongoid as a wrapper, rails_admin for creating admin interfaces

**I know that 'attr_accessible' no longer works for Rails4. So i have installed 'protected_attributes' gem.** But still no success i am still getting warning in my console

```
[RailsAdmin] Could not load model Company, assuming model is non existing. (undefined method `attr_accessible' for Company:Class)
```

So, rails admin do not load the class Company because i have defined attr_accessible in the model. Here is my company model.

```
  class Company
  include Mongoid::Document

  @@employees_strength = {0 => '0-10', 1 => '11-50', 2 => '51-100', 3 => '101-500', 4 => '501-1000', 5 => '1000+', 6 => '5000+'}

  field :name,          type: String
  field :website,       type: String
  field :domain_name,   type: String
  field :strength,      type: Integer

  has_many :employees
  has_one :admin, :class_name => 'Employee',  :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :organization

  #attr_accessible :name, :website, :domain_name, :strength#, :admin_attributes, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :admin_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin, :allow_destroy => true
 end
```

Please any can body can help?
Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same problem and figured I might as well share the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Mongoid 4 (<= 4.0.2 at the time of writing) does not know about the `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity` module provided by `protected_attributes` gem.

As such you must include the behaviour in your models manually e.g.

```
class SomeDocument
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

  field :some_field
  attr_accessible :some_field
end
```

However, this gets tedious pretty quickly so a reasonable alternative is to include the module into the `Mongoid::Document` module before any of your models are defined.

```
module Mongoid
  module Document
    include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
  end
end
```

Comment: seems like it doesn't work with Rails 4: 

uninitialized constant ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

Comment: @LevDenisov As mentioned, it's provided by the `protected_attributes` gem, it doesn't come with Rails 4 - you must add it to your Gemfile.